# Estimate on Integral of $e^{-u} \log u$ from $0$ to $s$ as $s \rightarrow 0+$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration

I am required to show that
$$\int_0^{s} e^{-u} \log u \, du = O(s|\log s|) \text{ as } s \rightarrow 0+$$
I tried using asymptotic estimates on $e^u$ as well as checking directly that the limit
$$\lim_{s \rightarrow 0+} \frac{1}{s|\log s|} \int_0^{s} e^{-u} \log u \, du$$
exists (by substituting $s:=1/t$ etc.) but couldn't get around the divergence of the integrand at $0$. I could recognize that the left side is the 'lower' partial integral of first derivative of the gamma function but that didn't help me much either. Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: How about using L'hospital's rule?

Comment: I tried that as well, got stuck while trying to differentiate the integral $\int_0^s e^{-u} \log u \, du$ as the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus or even Liebniz Integral Rule would make me look at the integrand $ e^{-u} \log u $ close to $0$, where I ran into the same problem. (Is there something I'm missing?)

Comment: Bound $e^{-u}$ by a constant. $\ln u$ has an elementary antiderivative.

Comment: Perfect, this works, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To expand on a  comment: The $e^{-u}$ is imply irrelevant; it's clear that it's bounded and also bounded above zero on $[0,1]$, so for $0<s<1$ we have $$A\int_0^s\log u\,du\le \int_0^s e^{-u}\log u\,du\le B\int_0^s\log u\,du.$$